# How to run code just for once in recyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my application I want use `RecyclerView` and for this I set **multiple layout** in `RecyclerView`.
**I changed layouts with button in fragment with below codes:**

```
public class AuctionCurrentFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @BindView(R.id.recyclerList)
    RecyclerView recyclerList;
    private ImageView list_item;
    private ArrayList countries = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private Context context;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private boolean clickFlag = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auction_current_tab, null);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        context = getActivity();
        list_item = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        recyclerList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new AuctionCurrentRecyclerAdapter(context, countries, 1);

        initViews();

        list_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clickFlag) {
                    adapter = new AuctionCurrentRecyclerAdapter(context, countries, 1);
                    recyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    clickFlag = false;
                } else {
                    adapter = new AuctionCurrentRecyclerAdapter(context, countries, 2);
                    recyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    clickFlag = true;
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    private void initViews() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            countries.add("Title " + i);
        }
        recyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

In one of layouts I use `progressBar` for show **count downer**, but when switch the `layouts` (with button in fragment) when show this layout set start again this count downer!
**But I want when switch layouts not start again, continue count downer.**

**Adapter codes :**

```
public class AuctionCurrentRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private ArrayList<String> countries;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    boolean isRunning = false;
    long timeInMillis;
    private int timeToEnd;
    private View view;
    private int itemLayout = 0;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;

    public AuctionCurrentRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> countries, int itemLayout) {
        this.context = context;
        this.countries = countries;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        switch (itemLayout) {
            case 1:
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_auction_large_new, viewGroup, false);
                return new LargeViewHolder(view);
            case 2:
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_auction_normal, viewGroup, false);
                return new NormalViewHolder(view);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        switch (itemLayout) {
            case 1:
                ((LargeViewHolder) viewHolder).tv_country.setText(countries.get(i));
                break;
            case 2:
                ((NormalViewHolder) viewHolder).tv_country.setText(countries.get(i));
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (itemLayout == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return countries.size();
    }

    public class LargeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tv_country, progressTxt;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        public LargeViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tv_country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_16962);
            progressTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressTxt);
            progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

            timeToEnd = new Random().nextInt(100);
            long timeInput = timeToEnd * 1000;
            timeInMillis = timeInput;
            progressBar.setMax((int) timeInMillis / 1000);
            isRunning = true;

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeInMillis, 100) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    progressTxt.setText("" + String.valueOf(Math.round(millisUntilFinished * 0.001f)));
                    progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(millisUntilFinished * 0.001f));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                }
            }.start();
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    }

    public class NormalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tv_country;

        public NormalViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tv_country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_16962);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I this ?

**But I want when switch layouts not start again, continue count downer.**

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446983/change-layout-screen-in-runtime-with-recyclerview-adapter Maybe useful to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating adapter everytime when you are clicking the listview.Instead Create a method inside you adapter to set the itemlayout

```
public void setItemLayout(int itemLayout){
    this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Inside your onclick method call the setItemLayout method.

```
if(adapter==null){
    adapter = new AuctionCurrentRecyclerAdapter(context, countries, 1);
    recyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
if (clickFlag) {
    adapter.setItemLayout(1);
    clickFlag = false;
} else {
    adapter.setItemLayout(2);
    clickFlag = true;
}
```

Comment: You still have to deal with the CountDownTimer, try to avoid creating objects  in the bindViewHolder and createViewHolder when possible to avoid lag when scrolling.

Comment: Can u see any objects created in onBindviewholder?

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(50);
```

this worked for me.

Recycler view executes only once.

Answer (score -1):

When assigning the adapter again to the recyclerView, the views and the ViewHolder are being created again, so your countDownTimer it is starting again. To modify the contents of RecyclerView, it is better not to recreate the adapter but call 'notifyDataSet()'.

About your problem, could you describe what you want to achieve? Do you really need to create a CountDownTimer in every ViewHolder? Also, notice that when doing it you are storing in always in the same countDownTimer, so you only have a reference to one of the countDowns. If this is not mandatory for your use case, you could have it declared int the RecyclerView.

Also, as a performance hint, it is recommended to avoid creating objects (allocating memory) in bindViewHolder() or createViewHOlder(), to avoid lag when scrolling content.

Comment: I would need to know what do you want to achieve, could you explain a little? Also take a look to Anonymous answer, its the way to proper modify the contents of the adapter, but you still need to deal with the CountDownTimer scenario, which depend on what you want to achieve.